# Constrain top anchor to bottom anchor of optional textview

Tags: ios, swift, constraints, subview

I have a label, commentLabel and a textview, statsLabel. They are part of a cell which contains a couple more labels (usernameLabel, checkinName, ...).

What I want to achieve, is for the statsLabel (in which the amount of likes and comments are displayed) is shown underneath the commentLabel. However, if the commentLabel is empty, I remove it from my subview (because otherwise the label still takes up 1 line without any text, bothering me with various autolayout issues).

What I do in my cell (UICollectionViewCell) class:

```
contentView.addSubview(commentTextview)
contentView.addSubview(statsLabel)
```

In my cellForItemAt method, I set the text of both items based on the string in an array, like so:

```
if let comment = feed[indexPath.item].commentText {

    cell.commentTextview.text = comment
    if(comment.isEmpty) {

        cell.commentTextview.removeFromSuperview()

    }

}
```

This works like a charm. The textview is removed when needed and is still visible when there is text. It works when there is text, but when it's empty (and thus removed), the statsLabel doesn't know where to constrain to, as I set a constraint like this in my cell class (override init):

```
statsLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: commentTextview.bottomAnchor, constant: 2).isActive = true
```

Any idea how I can make sure the constraint is bound to commentTextview when needed, but to usernameLabel when it's empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use a stack view because it would be easier for you to manage this kind of behaviour, but anyway you can set your constraint as a variable:

```
private lazy var topToCommentConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint = {
    let top = statsLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: commentTextview.bottomAnchor, constant: 2)
    top.isActive = true
    return top
}()

private lazy var topToUsernameConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint = {
    let top = statsLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: usernameLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 2)
    top.isActive = false
    return top
}()

if(comment.isEmpty) {

    cell.commentTextview.removeFromSuperview()
    topToCommentConstraint.isActive = false
    topToUsernameConstraint.isActive = true
}
```

Comment: Perfect. I have implemented this solution, but didn't use private vars, rather directly set it inside the if statement. It works for now - but I will look into StackView later and maybe replace it if necessary. Would it improve my app functionality or is it just easier to work with?

Comment: Good :) It depends on your layout but I suggest you to use a stack view because stack view is very flexible and manages automatically its subviews, so probably in this case you could take advantage of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create both constraints then activate/deactivate as needed.